# Cannot perform correctly spring-mvc mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-routing

I'm developing spring-mvc web-application and I faced some mapping problems:
My web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>pages/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

My controller:

```
 @Controller
    public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    PhotosService photosService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadIndex(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("firstName", "WWWALTER");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save( @ModelAttribute("document") PhotosEntity photosEntity,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        Blob blob = null;
        try {
            blob = new SerialBlob(file.getBytes());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      //  PhotosEntity photosEntity = new PhotosEntity();
        photosEntity.setContent(blob);
        photosEntity.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());

        photosService.saveFile(photosEntity);

        return "index";
    }
```

Also I have a application name in tomcat 7 -"c2". So should I map with "c2/" prefix?

Can you please help me create correct mapping?
I want to add an attribute in first method and retrieve it in jsp page:

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadIndex(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("firstName", "WWWALTER");
        return "index";
    }
```

- but this method isn't invoked.

Comment: What's the unexpected behavior you're seeing? We need more information about what exactly goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds so stupid. But I just forgot to put

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

in servlet context file. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the attribute like this: `${firstName}` from your jsp-page.

Also try changing `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)` to `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)`